# Missing Windows.System error in N=5 MvvmCross sample using XS on Mac

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm trying to compile the `N=5` solution from N+1 days of MvvmCross series (https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-05-MultiPage) using XS (Stable)` on a Mac. I'm getting the following error:

```
Error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Windows' does not exist in the namespace `System'. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0234) (MultiPage.Core)
```

This is triggered by the reference to `System.Windows.Input.ICommand`.

All the previous examples from the N+1 day series work without having to change assemblies. I was initially getting an additional error (missing `MvxCommand`) on this solution, which went away when I replaced the assemblies in `References` with the ones with same names but from `MvvmCross-Binaries` (from the XS-iOS-Mac folder). I also tried following the N=22 example (which is Mac-based) and applying it to N=5, with no avail.

It seems that anything that needs `ICommand` would be broken for me.

Any idea on how to fix this to compile on a Mac? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official support for PCLs is due any day now from Xamarin.

Until this comes along then support on the Mac requires a bit of .csproj editing in order to make the PC-nuget solutions build.

The easiest way to get these projects to build is:

- to switch the assembly hint paths from the `portable-win+net45+MonoAndroid16+MonoTouch40+sl40+wp71` path to the `MonoTouch40` path.
- and to add the System.Windows shim assembly to the list (the .Net and .Xml.Serialization shims may also be needed if your core project uses these areas)

After doing this in N=21, the references part of the Core csproj file looks like:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MvvmCross.PortableSupport.3.0.6\lib\MonoTouch40\System.Windows.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Cirrious.CrossCore">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore.3.0.6\lib\MonoTouch40\Cirrious.CrossCore.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Cirrious.MvvmCross">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MvvmCross.HotTuna.StarterPack.3.0.6\lib\MonoTouch40\Cirrious.MvvmCross.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Cirrious.MvvmCross.Localization">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore.3.0.6\lib\MonoTouch40\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Localization.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Json">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.Json.3.0.6\lib\MonoTouch40\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.JsonLocalisation">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.JsonLocalisation.3.0.6\lib\MonoTouch40\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.JsonLocalisation.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.ResourceLoader">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.ResourceLoader.3.0.6\lib\MonoTouch40\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.ResourceLoader.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.Json.3.0.6\lib\MonoTouch40\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Compare this to the original at https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-21-Babel/Babel.Core/Babel.Core.csproj

---

If this feels too 'hacky', then the alternative currently is not to use nuget, and instead to use the binaries folders - there's a walkthrough of this in N=22 - http://slodge.blogspot.com/2013/05/n22-from-basics-on-mac-n1-days-of.html

---

Hopefully, by the time I've finished writing this, then Xamarin will already have shipped their PCL support so this will be out of date...

Comment: It worked! Thanks, Stuart! Regarding PCL support in Xamarin, I understand it is 4 weeks away, based on this [recent tweet](https://twitter.com/migueldeicaza/status/345872095919632385), so having this workaround is deeply appreciated.